# "Archive:: command not found" while trying to use unzip command inside of shell function

Tags: bash, shell, command, sh, unzip

I have a very short script called "./wget_unzip.sh" :

```
#!/bin/sh
function wget_unzip {
    wget $1
    unzip ./patch\?zip
}

$(wget_unzip "https://www.mylinktoagerritpatch.org/patch?zip")
```

It should wget a tiny (~1KB) archive called "patch?zip" and then unzip it (inside there's a .diff file for a patch). This line

```
unzip ./patch\?zip
```

- is working fine while at the main body of script; however, if moved to inside of a function like above, it starts failing with

  ```
  ./wget_unzip.sh: line 7: Archive:: command not found
  ```

If I'd try to replace unzip with /usr/bin/unzip, I'll get another error:

```
./wget_unzip.sh: line 7: UnZip:: command not found
```

Everything is fine with another command - wget - so I wonder what's wrong with unzip...

Comment: `/bin/sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: Don't use `$( )` to run the `wget_unzip` function -- `$( )` is used to capture the output of a command, and use it as part of (or in this case the entire) command. Your function isn't outputting a command, so don't try to capture and execute its output.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with unzip, just how you called the function
remove the `$()`